# Justify Text in UILabel iOS

Tags: iphone, uilabel

I am having a problem that in iOS I am using UILabel to display 2,3 line text, I want to align text as justified but I am not finding any option to do so. Any suggestions how to make justify text in label?

i put these line to make start it from top

```
CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(300, 9999);
NSString *textString = someString;
UIFont *textFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Futura" size:14];
CGSize textStringSize = [textString sizeWithFont:textFont 
                               constrainedToSize:maximumSize 
                                   lineBreakMode:text.lineBreakMode];

CGRect textFrame = CGRectMake(10, 110, 300, textStringSize.height);
text.frame = textFrame;
```

so any trick like this to make it justfiy
Thanks

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There is now a convenient way to justify text since iOS6. You can create an instance of NSAttributedString, set appropriate properties and assign this attributed string to a text representing view such as UILabel, UITextView, etc. It's easy as this:

1. Create an instance of NSMutableParagraphStyle and set its properties.

   ```
   NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyles = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
   paragraphStyles.alignment = NSTextAlignmentJustified;      //justified text
   paragraphStyles.firstLineHeadIndent = 10.0;                //must have a value to make it work
   ```
2. Create NSDictionary for text attributes and create attributed string.

   ```
   NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyles};
   NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString: string attributes: attributes];
   ```
3. Set attributed string to a label.

   ```
   existingLabel.attributedText = attributedString;
   ```

Comment: "paragraphStyles.firstLineHeadIndent = 10.0"
that was it what im looking for. thanks!

Comment: Works like a charm!! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Can't be done I'm afraid - well not with UILabel.

You can use the **UIWebView** or a 3rd party library such as [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel)

Happy Coding :)

**Update:**

This answer has been obsolete since iOS6. Please refer to Tankista's answer.

Comment: this solution is now obsolete, check out my answer below

Answer (score 0):

It can be done easily, but you need to use Core Text.

subclass a `UIView`, add an `NSString` property, create an `NSAttributedString` and pass `kCTJustifiedTextAlignment` value for the `kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierAlignment` key, then draw the `NSAttributedString` using Quartz or CoreText in your drawrect method.

edit: `kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierAlignment` key `kCTJustifiedTextAlignment` value should be used to create a `CTParagraphStyleRef` struct and passed in as a value for `kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName` key when creating the `NSAttributedString`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned by @martin, my class [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel) can make this very easily.
(You will find it on my github and also find plenty of references to it on SO as well)

Comment: You have everything for that in the header file, no problem to do all of that. There is a ```UITextAlignmentJustify``` #define (that equals ```kCTJustifiedTextAlignment```) you can use to apply text alignment on your NSAttributedString (using ```setTextAlignment:lineBreakMode:``` method of NSAttributedString+Attributes.h).  And if you don't want the links to be clickable, there is also a @property for that : ```automaticallyAddLinksForType=0``` won't add any link on neither URLs, nor phones, nor anything.

Comment: Since iOS6, it is better to use native `UILabel` with `NSAttributedString`.

Comment: @Cœur Totally agreed (that's why `OHAttributedLabel` is deprecated since some time now, BTW). For those interested, I extracted all the handy `NSAttributedString` categories in my new [OHAttributedStringAdditions](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedStringAdditions) pod now, which helps you manipulate `NS(Mutable)AttributedString` objects more easily (and is compatible with iOS6+ and TextKit).

Answer (score 0):

**SWIFT 4.x**

version of approved answer:

1. Create an instance of NSMutableParagraphStyle and set its properties.

   ```
   let justifiedParagraphStyles: NSMutableParagraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle.init()
   justifiedParagraphStyles.alignment = .justified      //justified text
   justifiedParagraphStyles.firstLineHeadIndent = 10.0  //must have a value to make it work
   ```
2. Create NSDictionary for text attributes and create attributed string.

   ```
   let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle: justifiedParagraphStyles]
   let attributedString = NSAttributedString.init(string: string, attributes: attributes)
   ```
3. Set attributed string to a label.

   ```
   existingLabel.attributedText = attributedString
   ```